# How to access Excel sheet file path in other system

Tags: java

**Problem:** If I run my code which is converted to .JAR file in another system I am unable to access the EXCEL sheet path

```
InputStream Readexcel = null;
Readexcel = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Config.properties"); 
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Software\\Automation\\book1.xls");
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
```

Comment: What is the question? Please format the code.

Comment: If i run my code which is converted to .JAR file in other system i am unable to access the EXCEL sheet path

Comment: InputStream Readexcel = null; Readexcel=getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Config.properties");

Comment: "Unable how"? What is the resulting exception? What does happen? What not? Is the /Config.properties included in your .jar file? Does the book1.xls exist at that location?

Comment: Actually i need to run my code in some other  system which does not have selenium . so i converted my code to .JAR file . Now other system will not have the path which i mentioned in the code . how to access it ? kindly advice i am just started learning selenium

Comment: You wanted to access a folder which is not existed? Or you wanted to create a folder first in another system and put the excel file with the help of code to the path specify?

Comment: Let me know both the option .. so that i can learn ...  Or its more enough to know how to create a folder first in another system and put the excel file with the help of code to the path ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `Config.properties` in your jar as well.

If you are using eclipse to generate the jar then you need to check the checkbox against the resources folder also (if your `Config.properties` is in resources folder) while exporting the jar so that it will include the properties file in the jar file and becomes available.